# Break WhatsApp chat

Tags: chat, whatsapp

Is it possible to break/discover a WhatsApp chat?
If not - could you explain why?
As far as I know WhatsApp is a Facebook subsidiary... 
I've found a [post](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/whatsapp-update-security-bug-problem-backdoor-guardian-issue-how-to-safe-a7525506.html) on it with the following statement:

> An issue with the way that the app deals with the security keys
>   central to its encryption mean that people can actually spy on
>   messages, one security researcher has found. End-to-end encryption is
>   intended as a way of ensuring that messages can only be read by the
>   sender and their intended recipient, but the encryption keys that
>   power that technology can be a weak link if they are wrongly used.

Answer (score 1):

As the post is more than 2 years old by now, the setting the article talks about to fix it is now on by default. Meaning that you get a yellow message stating that your messages are end-to-end encrypted.

> the encryption keys that power that technology can be a weak link if they are wrongly used.

I interpret this 'wrongly used' as not using end-to-end encryption at all.
But every chat is encrypted by default now, you can see if your conversation is by checking if there is a yellow message in the beginning of a chat which states:

```
Messages to this chat and calls are now secured with end-to-end-encryption. Tap for more info.
```